# check duplicate values in oracle forms multi record block

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

What I wanted is to display an alert when I move to the next row if the record that I inserted is already one of the records in the multi record block.

[image]

and in what trigger must I put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options you can use.

One is to **POST** values entered (in WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE) trigger. It will, well, *post* everything you entered so far. Then, you can write a `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` trigger which `SELECTs` from that table and checks whether such a value already exists. Alternatively, if there's the `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on that (those) column(s), database will do its job itself, i.e. raise an exception.

Another option is to literally **loop** through all rows in a block and compare the first row's value with all the others, then the second row's values with all of them, etc.

Or, you can use a **Record Group** (usually used for Lists of Values). Basically, you'd check whether value you entered exists in a record group. More info, along with a FMB file, on [Craig's blog](https://sites.google.com/site/craigsoraclestuff/oracle-forms---how-to-s/oracle-forms).

Or, you can use **calculated items**, as described [enter link description here](http://sheikyerbouti.developpez.com/duplicates/duplicates.htm) (FMB attached as well).

As you can see, quite a few ways to do that; explore each of them and pick the one you find the most useful / attractive / easy to implement.